# How to add a html file into another html file?

Tags: html, css

lets pretend i've a html file - "**main.html**"
& another html file "**content.html**"

i want to add content on main. i made the content, where

```
 content's - Width = window.innerWidth || root.clientWidth || body.clientWidth;
    Height = window.innerHeight || root.clientHeight || body.clientHeight;
```

content is absolute. 
and i don't know the height width of main.

in main i added in the body part -

& this happen -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dt5tv.jpg)
here the can is from the content & texts are from the main..

the problem is content appears with its own scroll bar..

what to do...!?

Comment: Is that an iframe or something?

Comment: How about some code you are working on?

Comment: in main i added in the body part -

<object type="text/html" data="Aerosol BitBucket/index.html" width="100%" height="100%"
            style="overflow:auto;border:0px ridge blue; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
    </object>

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please use standard international English in which sentences begin with a capital letter, the word "I" is capitalized, and sentences end with a single full stop (period). Also, you don't need to thank people in advance for reading your question.

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically load content, you could make an AJAX call using `XMLHttpRequest()`.

In this example a url is passed to the `loadPage()` function, in which the loaded content is returned.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function loadPage(href)
            {
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.open("GET", href, false);
                xmlhttp.send();
                return xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div onClick="document.getElementById('bottom').innerHTML = 
                      loadPage('content.html');">Home</div>

        <div id="bottom"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

When the div element containing text of "Home" is clicked, it sets the html of div element with id of "bottom" to content found in the "hello-world.html" document at the same relative location.

**content.html**

```
<p>Your content</p>
```

Comment: sorry not working.. only "Home" appears in main.html at the top & thats not clickable..