# How to add a html file into another html file (with example)

Tags: javascript, html, oop, object

I asked the question [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39383773/how-to-add-a-html-file-into-another-html-file), couldn't get help. Here's agin -
I've a html file - "*main.html*" & another html file "*[content.html](http://pechasgamestudios.com/richmedia/aci/)*", where content is absolute &

```js
contentWidth = window.innerWidth || root.clientWidth || body.clientWidth;
contentHeight = window.innerHeight || root.clientHeight || body.clientHeight;
```

- I don't know the height & width of main.

When I add the content on main by adding this code to *main.html* body -

```js
<object type="text/html" 
        data="http://pechasgamestudios.com/richmedia/aci/"
        width="100%"
        height="560"
        style="overflow:auto;border:0px ridge blue; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
</object>
```

*main.html* became this - http://pechasgamestudios.com/richmedia/acitest/
Its not working well. There should be no scrollbar. What to do?

Comment: How does `http://pechasgamestudios.com/richmedia/aci/` generate the html? The problem is there. Post that code

Comment: Job done. Thanks mate.
From your previous deleted post:
in content: style: width: 100%; height: 100%;

previously it was "auto".

Comment: So I did undelete the post, you can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem stems from `http://pechasgamestudios.com/richmedia/aci/` add following style tag to canvas

```
style="width: 100%; height: 100%;";
```

Comment: Job done. Thanks mate.
Previously it was -
style="width: auto; height: auto;"

Comment: @FahadZaman: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. [See Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

As per [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp) for adding HTML file you can use `w3-include-html` attribute. 
For demo look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_html_include_1) .

Comment: After doing so, there is no sign of "content.html" on "main.html"
I want content to be absolute over the main, content width = main width.